# Outline/Stroke the formatted text

Tags: wpf, text-formatting

I am rendering the FormattedText with different foreground color to different character(fore example first two red, next 2 yellow like..), now i have to display outline surrounded to this text. For apply outline(stroke) i have to convert this FormattedText into geometry and then draw geometry like

Geometry textGeometry = FormattedText.BuildGeometry(new Point(_xOffset, _yOffset));
 drawingContext.DrawGeometry(null, new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(OutlineColor), storkeWidth),textGeometry);

but the problem is that it will render the FormattedText in red color and lost my formatting color.
am I missing something or there is another way to outline the text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think i found the solution.
first draw the formatted text and then the geometry, it will display the text as well as outline.

```
Geometry textGeometry = FormattedText.BuildGeometry(new Point(_xOffset, _yOffset)); 
drawingContext.DrawText(FormattedText,new Point(0,0));
drawingContext.DrawGeometry(null, new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(OutlineColor), storkeWidth),textGeometry);
```

If some has better approach please let me know.